# How to click accept on alert from website with PhantomJS?

Tags: python, phantomjs, alert

I am learning python and trying to fix existing code.

The script opens a page, clicks the accept button. This works fine, I believe. However, the site now displays a `javascript` alert and I need to accept that.

After lots of digging and attempting to use the suggestions from other posts, I have created the following code (I am not able to post it all, but this should be the relevant parts):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import getpass
from gmail import Gmail
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from time import sleep

#code block

self.chrome_session = webdriver.PhantomJS()

#code block

    for link_text, link_url in links:
        print("{0}: Clicking work order {1}.".format(datetime.datetime.now(),link_text))
        self.chrome_session.get(link_url)
        print("{0}: Attempting to accept".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
        try:
            potential_input = self.chrome_session.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//input[@value='Accept']"
            )
            sleep(1)
            potential_input.click()
            print("{0}: Accept clicked.".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
            sleep(5)
            try:
                alert = self.chrome_session.switch_to.alert
                print "Alert found"
                print alert
                alert.accept()
                print("{0}: Accepted work order {1}.".format(
                    datetime.datetime.now(),link_text
                ))
            except NoAlertPresentException:
                print "Alert not found"
        except Exception as inst:
            print type(inst)
            print inst.args
            print inst
            print("{0}: Accept input not found.".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
        self.chrome_session.back()
```

The script works until `alert.accept()`.

The alert displays two buttons: `Ok` and `Cancel`.

I have tried:

```
alert = self.chrome_session.switch_to().alert
alert = self.chrome_session.switch_to().alert()
alert = self.chrome_session.switch_to.alert
```

The most recent seems to be the closest. But, when it gets to `alert.accept()`, it throws the following error:

```
<selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert object at 0x7fface9de1d0>
<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>
()
Message: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding":"identity",
            "Connection":"close",
            "Content-Length":"53",
            "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Host":"127.0.0.1:55633",
            "User-Agent":"Python http auth"},
            "httpVersion":"1.1",
            "method":"POST",
            "post":"{\"sessionId\": \"94d3c650-ce28-11e7-a11e-17604cd282eb\"}",
            "url":"/accept_alert",
            "urlParsed":"anchor":"",
            "query":"",
            "file":"accept_alert",
            "directory":"/",
            "path":"/accept_alert",
            "relative":"/accept_alert",
            "port":"",
            "host":"",
            "password":"",
            "user":"",
            "userInfo":"",
            "authority":"",
            "protocol":"",
            "source":"/accept_alert",
            "queryKey":{},
            "chunks":["accept_alert"]},
            "urlOriginal":"/session/94d3c650-ce28-11e7-a11e-17604cd282eb/accept_alert"}
```

How do I get it to recognize the alert, and accept it?

**UPDATE**

It seems that the `javascript` alert doesn't open with the script. I am not sure if it makes a difference, but the "Accept" button that I click prior to the alert is below:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept" 
       onclick="javascript:updateAcceptorRejectFlag(1)" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Is it possible that I am calling it incorrectly and so the alert doesn't actually display?